# PHP xmlreading and strlen/if statement error

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I got an xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pluginlist>
    <plugin>
        <pid>1</pid>
        <pluginname>ChatLogger</pluginname>
        <includepath>pugings/</includepath>
        <cmds>say
        </cmds>
        <cmds>sayteam</cmds>

        <cmds>tell</cmds>

    </plugin>
</pluginlist>
```

And a php was something like this :

```
<?php 
        $xml_pluginfile="pluginlist.xml";
        if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_pluginfile)){
            trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
        }
        foreach($xml as $plugin){
            echo $plugin->pid." : ";
            foreach($plugin->cmds as $value)
            {
                echo $value." ". strlen(value)."<br />";
            }
            echo "<br />";
        }
?>
```

The output i get is :

```
1 : say 5
sayteam 5
tell 5
```

Why do i get the length of each output as 5 ?

and when i try to do this :

```
if($value)=="say"
```

Why is this happening ?

Please help me
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because there it whitespace in one of the `<cmds>` tags. You can fix this by removing the whitespace or by using the following to your PHP code:

```
foreach($plugin->cmds as $value)
{
    $value = trim($value); // removes whitespace from the start or end of
                           // the string
    // ...
}
```

Also: `strlen(value)` should also be changed to `strlen($value)`.

Comment: 1)Then why do on sayteam still i get 5 ?

Comment: You can see output i just pasted it here

Answer (score 2):

```
<cmds>say
        </cmds>
```

the XML file you pasted above has a "\n\t" after the "say" and before the "`</cmds>`", so they are the 2 extra characters.

\n for new line
\t for tab

you can use "trim()" to clean them.

EDIT::

TOTALL MISSED THAT

your statement

```
echo $value." ". strlen(value)."<br />";
```

it should be $value instead of value in the strlen();

:)

Comment: 1)Then why do on sayteam still i get 5 ?

Comment: Edited answer, you have "value" in strlen, instead of $value, PHP is assuming it to be constant string "value" and hence strlen = 5

Comment: I know i noticed it when @TimCooper i noticed it I DONT KNOW HOW I COULD BE SUCH A BLIND lol

Answer (score 0):

The error is that strlen() has a literal string as input rather than the variable; you missed to prepend value with a $.

Replace your echo with this:

```
echo $value . " " . strlen($value) . "<br />";
```

Hope it helps.